# Is it possible to open Chrome process and execute javascript on a website in the Chrome window?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, process, code-injection, inject

For a C# WPF application I'm creating, I would like to open a website in Google Chrome.
Chrome is standalone and totally independent from my application.
I start Chrome like the following:

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://www.example.com");
```

So an independent process is started, which is the Chrome instance that loads the desired web address.

What I would like to do, is running arbitrary javascript code on the loaded webpage. Like if the javascript code would be 'injected'.
I do not control the loaded website.

The purpose is to open a third-party webpage and pre-fill in some form fields so the user doesn't have to do this all time.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only do this in a clean way through a Chrome extension that you allow to communicate with a desktop application. This way the user has to explicitly allow your extension to do this. For security reasons I doubt Chrome leaves you many other choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I've done this many time using Seleniums's JavaScriptExecutor.
You'll want to launch Chrome using the Selenium Driver instead of launching the Chrome process yourself.

https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html

From their example:

```cs
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript(Script,Arguments);
```